# Microservice pattern for login and sign up

Tags: node.js, authentication, design-patterns, microservices

I am doing a project with microservices. For login and sign up service I have used Nodejs. I used express, bcrypt, passport and it is working. I am planning to use JWT now.
What mistake I did is I think I am working in backwards. Which pattern would be best for login and sign up now? Is access token will be perfect?
Can anything added extra?

Comment: I strongly recommend one of the enterprise SSO protocols where one service acts as an Identity Provider. There are at least two strong candidates, the OpenIDConnect and SAML. Picking one of the two will let you not only integrate your own services around but also easily attach other systems to the one ecosystem.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will check about both and compare them to choose.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest that you should use OAuth protocol for authentication and authorization. In my past projects, we were using Auth0 service (paid one). There are several other option that support OAuth one like Azure AD etc.. It support JWT token as well.